# Diehard test only integers?

Tags: random, testing, numbers

I want to test some "random" numbers in (0 1). I will test them with the diehard tests battery, But I don't know, if it tests numbers in (0 1). So diehard test any kind of numbers, or it just test intergers?

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests) on the Diehard tests makes no specification that the tests are for integers only, and some of the tests (specifically, the squeeze, runs, and overlapping sums tests) are explicitly done on [0,1). None of the others seem like they would be integer-only from a cursory glance.

Comment: i have seen in the diehard.doc, stored in the diehard.zip this sentence:
 The tests in DIEHARD require that you provide a large binary
  file of random integers to be tested. that's why i am confused.

Comment: Even if that's the case, can't you just multiply all the floats on [0,1) by some large constant? Statistically, the distribution (standard deviation, etc.) of the numbers would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Vanesa :
There is version 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8, which are compiled for Windows and VC + + 6.0. This version produced a basic charts with the results of the tests but also allows selection between a binary file 32-bit hexadecimal numbers or a bit ascii file like yours.

Here is the URL to download and to open with VS2008 you have to correct some basic errors. I compile it in VC + + 2008

http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/implement/rng/distrib/

Greetings, Edwin

Comment: This version are NIST test suite, better that DIEHARD tets

Answer (score 1):

I would not go that i had the same problem as Vannesa what i did was just download lastest NETBEANS IDE install the C/C++ plugin donwloaded CYWIN http://netbeans.org/community/releases/60/cpp-setup-instructions.html then download the source  from  and compile and test and it works fine, all test work even on a simple hex number with the exception of OVerlapping Permutation wich gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still interested in the answer. Run ASC2BIN.EXE. It describes what you have to do. There also is a .doc-file in the diehard-folder that describes every step you have to make. Its not very intuitive, though.

In principle:
Create 3 million 32-bit integers between 0 and INT_MAX. Create an ascii file containing these integers in hex form, that is 8(!) hex digits per number, 80 characters per line. Give it a name with less than 15 characters. Run ASC2BIN.EXE, feed it your file and enjoy ;-).

Oh and if anybody has floats on 0,1 than you need to convert them into the integers that I described above (could multiply by INT_MAX). Yes, diehard uses floats at some places, but it creates these itself from your converted file.

Comment: Do you still have a source of the folder?